# How is tension the force that causes an elevator to ascend or descend?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When we draw a FBD of an elevator we often use the tension force as the force pulling on the elevator, and gravity as the force "pushing" on the elevator. If the mass of the elevator cable is 0, it is to my understanding that the tension within the cable is constant. That means the two tension forces in each direction cancel out. How is it then, that we can consider tension as the cause of the elevators ascending or descending motion. The only solution I can think of is the fact that we can only consider the forces on the elevator it self. Tension is the only force acting on the elevator in the y direction (and gravity). But once again, this solution leads me to the question: doesn't tension going down cancel with the tension going up?

Also another solution I thought of was the fact that tension is simply a pulling force. Therefore we can only consider the tension force that is pulling on the elevator, not the opposing it. Is it right of me to think of it this way?

Comment: If you consider the tension down too, then you have to consider the whole system, which is the elavator PLUS the weights which move down. The system as a whole does not move then due to the tensions (they cancel), only the individual components of the system move w.r.t. each other due to internal forces (tension again). Sorry for the awful explanation. Ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: If you'd like to write that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Comment: The two different tension don't cancel each other out because they are acting on two different bodies. When we raise the argument that why doesn't the action reaction forces cancel each other out even though they have same magnitude , the answer lies in the fact that action-reaction pair act on two different bodies so they cannot cancel each other out.

Comment: The two tension are applied on the same system so they cancel out. For example, a box being applied F force on both sides (opposite direction) technically has the forces on different sides, but the internal mechanism (rigidity) ensures that there is no net movement hence we say the force cancels. The body isn't moving, means that a whole series of internal forces cancel out each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that each object, or part of an object can have its own FBD. You can chop the cable in arbritarily small chuncks, where each chunck has its own FBD and force-balance.

However, what was also mentioned in one of the comments, if you consider the force of two neighbouring FBD's together, the connecting forces disappear from the FBD. This does not mean that the forces are not there, they simply do not have a contribution to the system as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Disgram]
Somewhat related to my question. What would the FBD of this look like? What are the action reaction forces acting on the system?

Comment: I'm not sure why this picture is so big, or how to make it smaller.

Comment: Total acceleration of the system will be net force/total mass which will be equal to 4m/s^2. Choose any mass, apply Newtons 2nd law and you can get the value of tension..The direction of tension is always away from the body to which the rope is connected to...Like in the 3kg mass the tension will be down..The action reaction pair would be the tension with which the string pulls the body down and the reaction with which the body pulls the string up...(this is not a motion under gravity)...

Comment: It's supposed to be horizontal, but the picture came out vertical. However I do get what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: In a lift..There is actually a counterweight that is connected to the lift by strong wires around a pulley..The motion in a pulley is not similar to this..But the direction of the tension is always away from the point where the rope touches the body...This because tension can only pull and not push...So, you can apply Newtons laws and get the tension in a pulley system too if you get the directions of the forces in a FBD correct..